# Geometry Triangle Question 3

Tags: geometry

1. In the triangle shown, $n$ is a positive integer, and $\angle A > \angle B > \angle C$. How many possible values of $n$ are there?

[image: Diagram]

2. Two sides of an acute triangle are 8 and 15. How many possible lengths are there for the third side, if it is a positive integer?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you done to attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: I tried triangle inequality...

Comment: Please show how you used the triangle inequality in these problems. That way, we can build off of your work in our answers and we will know what you know, so we won't overexplain/underexplain things.

Comment: I don't know where to start for problem (1), but for problem (2) I think you can set up equations using triangle inequality, but I don't know if the word "acute" affects anything in the problem.

Comment: The greatest side is opposed to the greatest angle and the shortest side is opposed to the smallest angle. The side lengths have to be positive and fulfill the triangle inequality. What else do you need?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Really? I have $\cos A $ negative for $n=4 $

Answer (score 1):

The best way to start with question 1 is to make a table for feasible low values of $n$ and see where that takes you, since this is unlikely to be a question that has "general-purpose" results. Note that the side opposite $\angle A$ is length $a$ etc.
\begin{array}{c|c} 
n & a & b & c & \text{notes} \\ \hline
3 & 13 & 10 & 3 & \text{not a triangle} \;\;\times \\
4 & 16 & 13 & 7 & \text{A obtuse, }13^2+7^2<16^2 \\
5 & 19 & 16 & 11 & \text{A acute, }16^2+11^2>19^2 \\
6 & 22 & 19 & 15 & \\
7 & 25 & 22 & 19 & \\
8 & 28 & 25 & 23 & \\
9 & 31 & 28 & 27 & \\
10 & 34 & 31 & 31 & \text{isosceles}\;\;\times\\
\end{array}
It's apparent that $ \angle B < \angle C$ for larger $n$, so we have $6$ viable values for $n, 4..9$.

Question 2 requires the application of Pythagoras' theorem for the high and low limits of the third side length (since the problem requires an acute triangle):
$$15^2+8^2 = 289 = 17^2 \\
15^2-8^2 = 161 < 13^2$$

So the third side can have integer lengths $13..16$