# A Question about Triangle Inequality

Tags: geometry

Two sides of an acute triangle are 8 and 15. How many possible lengths are there for the third side, if it is a positive integer?

I'm not sure if the word "acute" affects the problem.

If not, is the answer 15?

I tried using triangle inequality.

Comment: Please look at [the bottom of this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1825291/307483) for more about this same problem. Also, when you used the triangle inequality, how did you get $15$? Please show all of your work so we can find your mistake. You can use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to help format the inequalites in your work.

Comment: Triangle inequality is the right approach.  An acute triangle is one in which all three angles are acute (less than a right angle).  Because the third side must be a positive integer, there are only a finite number of possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Well acute makes a difference.

You must know that $(8,12.68..,15)$ are Pythagoras triplets. Thus third side must be greater that $12,$ else you will have an obtuse angle.

Next you must also note that $(8,15,17)$ are also Pythagoras triplets. Thus, the third side must be less than $17$.

Thus set of all possible values of the third side is $\{13, 14, 15, 16\}$